# Prove that $5^{2^n}−1$ contains exactly $n+2$ factors $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

I have to prove that $5^{2^n}−1$ contains exactly $n+2$ factors $2$ and then I have to show that the order of $5$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z})^*$ equals $2^{n−2}$ (for $n ≥ 2$).

I know that for the first part I can use $5^{2^{n+1}} −1 = (5^{2^{n}} −1)(5^{2^{n}} +1)$, but then I do not know to continue.

Comment: I don't understand the question. "contains exactly n+2 factors 2" what does that mean?

Comment: @Ameet Sharma   We need to prove that $5^{2^n}-1$ is divisible by $2^{n+2}.$

Comment: oh ok. thanks. I see.

Answer (score 3):

$5^{2^n}+1$ is even and not divisible by $4$.

Thus, it's enough to check that $5^2-1$ is divisible by $8$ and your statement is true by induction.

Comment: Or even $5^{2^0}-1$ divisible by $4$ ;)

Comment: @metamorphy  It's divisible by $2^8$. It follows from the induction.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick response. I shall try to prove it.

Comment: I mean $n=\color{red}{0}$ as the base. $5^{2^{\color{red}{0}}}-1$ is divisible by $4$ (because it is *equal* to $4$).

Comment: @metamorphy  Oh yes of course! I just saw $5^{2^6}-1.$ I did not see $0$. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The OP can keep using the general identity $a^2 - 1 = (a+1)(a-1)$ to factor the integer.

For $n \ge -1$,

$\tag 1 5^{2^{n+1}} −1 = 
4 \,{\displaystyle \prod _{k=0}^{n}\, (5^{2^{k}} +1)}$